# CMake: Building Multiple Libraries with the same code but with different include paths

Tags: c++, cmake, static-libraries, include-path, lammps

I have a source code that interfaces with LAMMPS. For the reasons that are beyond the scope of this forum, however, I have to maintain two working versions of my code, each compatible with a different version of LAMMPS. Therefore, I need to compile two libraries from the same code: each having been compiled against the corresponding LAMMPS source code. How can I do that in CMake?

So the question is, say you have the source code a1.cpp, a2.cpp, ...., aN.cpp. All these sources codes include code from another package. But I want to use different include paths for each round of compilation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`target_include_directories()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_include_directories.html) and [`target_link_libraries()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html) to define a per-target lib include/linking.